# OpenCV and RAD studio C++ (getting started)

Tags: c++, opencv, rad

This is my first time on the board and I want to use OpenCV with RAD studio C++. I spend a lot of time, searching and trying how to start with OpenCV and RAD studio but without result.

There are a lot of tutorials with visual studio but can't find any with RAD studio from Embarcadero. I'm wondering if someone on this board is using RAD studio and wants to help, how to start with OpenCV and RAD studio.

Greetings, DreeOlee

Edit_15/12/2012: I added the library's to the settings. See picture. Than I tried opening a sample file in the tutorial folder, "display_image.cpp" and got a lot of errors, see picture. Can anyone help? I don't have any handles to get started at this moment.

[image: Errors]

[image: libs]

EDIT: Changing to other IDE because:  http://code.opencv.org/issues/2057